# How can I refer a laravel route to different api controllers based on type of the model type injected in the route?

Tags: api, conditional-statements, laravel-routing

I have an apiResource route whose URL contains a factory and a product model.
Depend on the product type, I need two different controllers. I also need to inject factory instance and product instance to both controllers. Something like this:

```
Route::apiResource('factories/{factory}/products', function(Product $product) {
if ($product->type == 'typeA') {
Route::apiResource('factories/{factory}/typeAs', 'TypeAController')
}
if ($product->type == 'typeB') {
Route::apiResource('factories/{factory}/typeBs', 'TypeBController')
}
}
```

1- The first question is what the correct way to do so is and how I should define the routes?
2- The second question is: product instance is injected into the main URL by its slug. I need the product instance to be injected in both sub routes. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use binding route in `RouteServiceProvider`. When your route have `factory` parameter, it returns you a model of factory which has `product_id`:

```
public function boot()
    {
        Route::bind('factory', function () {
            $product_type = \App\Models\Factory::where('{factory}', request()->type);

            return $product_type->firstOrFail();
        });

        parent::boot();
    }
```